# Нахолодавший загробок. Значение словосочетания

Tags: словарь

Опять же, не нашёл значения такого словосочетания.

Контекст: Конец апреля, когда земля млеет под тёплым ветром, благодатно поставляет солнцу нахолодавший и мокрый загробок.

Comment: Контекст: Конец апреля, когда земля млеет под тёплым ветром, благодатно поставляет солнцу нахолодавший и  мокрый загробок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, здесь у Вас элементарная опечатка.
Нахолодавший за**горб**ок. Замерзшие плечи, верхняя часть спины. *Нахолодеть* может и другая часть тела человека или животного. 
Сравните у Шолохова :

> На правом берегу офицер в парусиновой рубахе гаркнул:
>
> -- Пре-кра-тить стрельбу!...
>
> Через пять минут Трофим был возле жеребенка, левой рукой **подхватил его под нахолодевший живот**, захлебываясь, судорожно икая, двинулся к левому берегу... С правого берега не стукнул ни один выстрел.

Comment: Спасибо, вам.

Comment: Украинский. гробки́. 1. кладбище. 2. проводы (поминальное воскресенье после праздника пасхи).
Есть такие топонимы, там же -- Гробки. Можно зайти за Гробки, но загробок, точно загорбок, ошибка при наборе.

Comment: >1. кладбище. 2. проводы (поминальное воскресенье после праздника пасхи).

В 1-ом смысле слово "гробки" практически не употребляется. Но, да, в словарях я его тоже нашёл. :-) 

Странно, что это значение идёт там под номером 1.

.

Слово "гробки" я встречал в разговорной речи и только в смысле *"поминальное воскресенье после праздника Пасхи"*.

Answer (score 2):

Откуда вы их берете? 
Это что-то или очень диалектное, или окказионализм (в широком значении, т.е. всякое нарочито придуманное слово и сочетание).

Вот мне подсказывают, что "загробок" это может буть что-то геймерское: какой-то артефакт или таблетка в РПГ/ММОРГах.

Comment: Нет. Это художественное произведение около 70 года сочинения.